# Remove empty <ul> tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have code like above

```
     ` <ul id="jsddm">

                            <li><a href="Default.aspx">
                                Menu</a>
                                <ul style="visibility: hidden;">


                                            <li><a href="Content.aspx?ID=153">
                                                SubMenu</a></li>


                                            <li><a href="Content.aspx?ID=152">
                                                SubMenu</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">
                                Menu</a>
                                <ul style="visibility: hidden;">

                                </ul>
                            </li>

                </ul>
            </div>`
```

I want to romove empty sub **"ul"** tags which is has got not **"li"** tag(s) with jquery when my page onload.
How can I do? Thanks for help.

Comment: Not to be overly picky, but with all that leading space in your code, I can't see it on my iPhone. I believe on a pc it'll show with scrollbars, but still. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("ul").each(
  function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.children().length == 0) {
      elem.remove();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes, this method works perfect too as Manticore's proposal. Thank you very much for your help too.

Answer (score 29):

```
$('ul').not(':has(li)').remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery `:empty` selector would work if your UL elements really were *empty*, and didn't contain any white space.

To check for both empty and elements with white space you could do something like this:

```
$("#jsddm ul").each(function(i, el) {
    // Remove white space
    var html = $(el).html().replace(/\s+/, "");

    // Check if element is :empty or length of html is zero
    if ($(el).is(":empty") || html.length == 0)
        $(el).remove();
});
```

Comment: Just check the child count like Zed and Aistina did... that's just overly complicated

Comment: Yes, I used Zed's proposal for my issue as you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$('#jsddm ul').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

It removes all the `<ul>` elements under the element with id jsddm which do not contain child nodes.

Comment: Great idea to check the children count!

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
$('li ul:empty').remove();
```

will do what you want.

Comment: This would work if it weren't for the fact you have a lot of whitespace in your UL element. This makes the `:empty` selector return false.

Comment: I could not understand what it did not work. if you want i can send all html output codes.

Comment: i think empty means "if tag has got not attribute" does is? if which i said, fact question may be like this; i want remove ul tag which it has'nt got <li> tag(s)!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jsddm ul").empty();
});
```

Comment: Thank you too, This code removed all ul tags under jsddm's. But i want to remove only empty ul tags.